# What does "≤⊕≥" mean?

Tags: notation, relations

I just meet a symbol ≤⊕≥ in question "does the relation defined by (≤⊕≥) is the same as the relation ≠？", but I checked the Glossary of mathematical symbols, but did not find it, does anyone know it?

Comment: In what context did you meet it? Can you share an example sentence and relevant objects used around it?

Comment: A wild guess. Both comparisons are actually relations, so sets. The Oplus sign in between may mean a binary sum XOR. In such case the result is the whole product set without the diagonal, so the relation “not equal”

Comment: As Al.G. said, the context of use is critical : there are dozens of use of this symbol in mathematics.

Comment: For example, I met it in P.R. Halmos - Finite-dimensional vector spaces-Springer-Verlag (1974), page 28, for the **direct sum** conception. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: @Al.G. I checked the wikipedia's Glossary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols, and did not find it. The question is the "relation defined by ≤⊕≥".

Comment: @SBF "XOR" this is not the most common use of $\oplus$... The most common use, IMHO, is "direct sum of two (sub)spaces" but there are so many others...

Comment: @HelenGuo Please provide the context.

Comment: @IraeVid the question is "does the relation defined by (≤⊕≥) is the same as the relation ≠"

Comment: This may well be a symbol introduced in a specific problem or part of a book. Without more information, e.g. which book, or a longer sentence, then this problem is almost surely impossible to answer.

Comment: @user1729 This is a homework I met in my school, I just learned binary relation and set operation, and the whole  question is "True or false: Over integers, the relation defined by (≤⊕≥) is the same as the relation ≠".

Comment: Ohh, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JeanMarie well, I guessed. in logic I saw this often during my grad classes, whereas I saw direct sum of spaces notation more in linear algebra. Here the question is about logic/set theory, given $\leq$ and $\geq$

Comment: @SBF You were right !

Comment: @HelenGuo what you say in your last 2 comments is exactly what I asked about: you're talking about *relations of natural numbers* in the context of *set theory* plus the relevant question sentence. If you included this information right from the start in the question, you wouldn't see the next 13 clarifying comments below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol $⊕$ denotes XOR (exclusive or), so $\leq⊕\geq$ would denote $\leq$ XOR $\geq$. Let's create a table. Note that at least one of $\leq$ and $\geq$ must be true.

| $\leq$ | $\geq$ | $\leq⊕\geq$ | $\neq$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | True | True | True |
| True | False | True | True |
| True | True | False | False |

From this table, we can see that $\leq⊕\geq$ is logically equivalent to $\neq$. Hence, the answer is **Yes**.

Comment: "Note that .." It should be in question, not in answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand, so it means, we need to satisfy one of ≤ and ≥, but not both.

Comment: @zkutch What do you mean? Which part? The "at least one of" part?

Comment: @HelenGuo Yes, that is what XOR means.

Comment: In question, there is not restriction for "False False" line, especially since xor is the same as the negation of equivalence for all four possible lines.

Answer (score 0):

$\leq⊕\geq$ means $\leq$ xor $\geq$. If you think about it, if $\leq$ is true but $\geq$ is not true, this will imply that $\neq$ must be true, or else both $\leq$ and $\geq$ will be true, and vice versa. If both $\leq$ and $\geq$ are true, this will impy that $=$ must be true, which in turn means that $\neq$ must be false. Clearly, $\neq$ is the same as $\leq⊕\geq$.